# Is there any existing Library for this kind of image viewer?

Tags: ios, swift, image, viewer

I can't explain it properly when searching in google, so I hope someone here is able to point it out for me. If there are no existing libraries, then, I'll have to manually create it and you might be able to give me hints of how I should implement it. Thank you very much!

[image][image]

Comment: Look at iCarousel

Comment: It sounds like you want the effect called “coverflow”. Yes, iCarousel supports it. Yuo can also find examples of how to do it with a custom `UICollectionViewLayout` by asking your favorite search engine.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can check following libraries to get your desired result.

1> [iCarousal](https://github.com/nicklockwood/iCarousel)

2> [YRCoverflow](https://github.com/solomidSF/YRCoverFlowLayout)

3> [Scaling Carousal](https://github.com/superpeteblaze/ScalingCarousel)

4> [LNICoverflowLayout](https://github.com/sumitlni/LNICoverFlowLayout)